# Replace values by using names()

Tags: r

I have a df with a column with values ex.
   `4,5,6,7,3,1,1,3`
I want another column in this df based on these values.
I have key pair with names() (names on top)

```
one det somet ish hir  whynot
 4  5    6     7  3    1
```

I want a new column based on this second vector with its names in place of column one's values based on second vector

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 df$v2 <- setNames(names(v2), v2)[as.character(df$v1)]
```

Or use `match`

```
 df$v2 <- names(v2)[match(df$v1, v2)]
```

#### data

```
 df <-  structure(list(v1 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 1, 3)), .Names = "v1",
   row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

 v2 <- c('one'=4, 'det'=5, 'somet'=6, 'ish'=7, 'hir'=3, 'whynot'=1)
```